# On the generalized Sierpinski space

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, set-theory

In Sierpiński topology the open sets are linearly ordered by set inclusion, i.e.  If  $S=\{0,1\}$, then the Sierpiński topology on $S$ is the collection $\{ϕ,\{1\},\{0,1\} \}$ such that
$$\phi\subset\{0\}\subset\{0,1\}$$
we can generalize it by defining a topology analogous to Sierpiński topology with nested open sets on any arbitrary non-empty set as follows:
Let $X$ be a non-empty set and $I$ a collection of some nested subsets of $X$ indexed by a linearly ordered set $(\Lambda,\le)$  such that $I$ always contains the void set $ϕ$ and the whole set $X$, i.e. 
                       $$I=\{\emptyset,A_\lambda,X:A_\lambda\subset X ,\lambda\in\Lambda\}$$
such that   $A_\mu⊂A_\nu$  whenever  $\mu\le\nu$.

Then it is easy to show that $I$ qualifies as a topology on $X$.

My questions are -

(1) Is there a name for such a topology in general topology literature?

(2) Is there any research paper studying such type of compact, non-Hausdorff and connected chain topologies?

Comment: This seems to be similar to obtaining [Alexandroff topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_topology) from a poset. (Although it is not the same.) In this case the poset would be linearly ordered. See also: [Specialization preorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specialization_preorder).

Comment: For (2): Isn't such space compact $\Leftrightarrow$ $(\Lambda,\le)$ has a smallest element?

Comment: @ Martin...you mean it is not always compact for all linearly ordered $(Λ,≤)$.

Comment: If you put $(\Lambda,\le)=(\mathbb Z,\le)$ with the usual order and $A_\lambda=\{x\in\mathbb Z; x\ge\lambda\}$ then it is not compact. Maybe I misunderstood your question (2). I thought that you are asking *when* such spaces are compact. (And the other properties.)

Comment: The topology is $S=\{\varnothing,\{1\},\{0,1\}\}$. The empty set is an element, not a singleton. Also $\phi$ is not the empty set. You can have `\varnothing` or `\emptyset` for the symbol of the empty set instead.

Comment: @Martin $A_λ\subset X$ and $Λ$ is the index set.Please read the whole formulation again.

Comment: @ Asaf thanx. I edited.

Comment: I my example $X=\Lambda=\mathbb Z$. I still think it's an example of a non-compact space obtained by your construction.
If needed, we can continue the discussion about this example [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3784/generalized-sierpinski-space), in order to avoid putting too many comments at your question.

Comment: what is then your definition of $A_\lambda$? since $A_\lambda=\{x\in\mathbb Z; x\ge\lambda\}$ does not satisfy $A_μ⊂A_ν$ whenever $μ≤ν$.

Comment: Ok, I should have taken $\mathbb Z$ with the opposite order, not the usual order. 
The other possibility would be putting $A_\lambda=\{x\in\mathbb Z; x\le\lambda\}$ and leave the usual order.

Comment: Why is $I$ a topology? Particularly, why is it closed under arbitrary unions? Consider the case $\Lambda = \mathbb{Q}, A_\lambda = (-\infty, \lambda)$.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen what is $X$? since $A_\lambda\subset X$

Comment: @MartinSleziak in this type of topology every open cover must contain $X$ itself. This is also applicable to your example as well.

Comment: BTW the same question was posted at MO, but it was closed there: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/99783/on-the-compactness-of-a-certain-chain-topology-closed

Answer (score 1):

This was already pointed out in comments, but I'm collecting this into an answer. (In fact, this is closer to a longer comment than to an answer, but the details can be elaborated better here than in a short comment.)

Both examples here deal with your construction in the special case that $X=\Lambda$. And in both cases we work with the sets of the form
$(-\infty,a)=\{x\in\Lambda; x<a\}$, which is similar to [lower topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_topology).

---

As noticed by Niels Diepeveen, see [his comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158606/on-the-generalized-sierpinski-space#comment366449_158606), this is not necessarily a topology.

Suppose that we have $X=\Lambda$ and $A_\lambda=(-\infty,\lambda)=\{x\in\Lambda; x<\lambda\}$.

This means that for each bounded subset $D\subseteq\Lambda$ there exists a $\lambda$ such that  $\bigcup_{\mu\in D} A_\mu = A_\lambda$. It is relatively easy to show that the last condition is equivalent to $\lambda=\sup_{\mu\in D} \mu$. I.e. the linear order would have to be [complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Completeness).

A counterexample suggested by Niels is $\Lambda=X=\mathbb Q$. For example if $(q_n)$ is an increasing sequence of rational numbers such that $q_n\to\sqrt{2}$, then $\bigcup (-\infty,q_n)=(-\infty,\sqrt2)$, which is not of the form $A_\lambda$.

There are several possibilities how to circumvent this. E.g. you could take all [downward closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down-set) sets as open. Or you could take $\{\emptyset,X,A_\lambda; \lambda\in\Lambda\}$ as a base for the topology you want to generate.

---

Even if this is a topology, it need not necessarily be compact.

Let us take $X=\Lambda=\mathbb Z$.

Again $A_\lambda=\{x\in\mathbb Z; x<\lambda\}=(-\infty,\lambda)\cap\mathbb Z$. I.e. $A_\lambda$'s are down-sets of the linearly ordered set $\mathbb Z$.

Now if $\mathcal C$ is open cover of $X$ then, for each $n\in\mathbb Z$, the cover $\mathcal C$ must contain some $A_\lambda$ with $\lambda>n$. This shows that every open cover is infinite.

And if we take $\mathcal C=\{A_n; n\in\mathbb Z\}=\{(-\infty,n)\cap\mathbb Z; n\in\mathbb Z\}$, we get an open cover which does not have a finite subcover.

Comment: @Martin...Thanx for the answer.

Comment: @ Martin...can you tell me the areas where such topologies with nested open sets can be found? any article/research paper?

Comment: Well I have already mention [Alexandrov spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_topology) (also called finite generated space). Wikipedia article has some papers among references. However, I don't know whether they were studied for the special case of linear orderings.